# CollectionViewSource unselect selectedItem when clicking a group name

Tags: wpf, xaml, collectionviewsource

I have a `listbox` that has its `itemSource` bound to a `collectionViewSource` that is grouped and has 2 levels of groupings over the actual items:

```
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myCVS}}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myItemsTemplate}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource myItemsStyle}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedListItem}" >
            <ListBox.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}" />
                <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource SubHeaderStyle}" />
            </ListBox.GroupStyle>
        </ListBox>
```

With a `CollectionViewSource` bound to an `ObservabeleCollection`:

```
       <CollectionViewSource x:Key="myCVS" Source="{Binding Path=myItemsToGroup}">
            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="HeaderName" />
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="SubHeaderName" />
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
```

the items in the `ObservalbleCollection` look like:

```
public class Items
{
    public string GroupName;
    public string SubGroupName;
    public string ItemName;
}
```

This all works great i end up with:

```
Header1
 |_SubHeader1
     |_item1
     |_item2
Header2
 |_SubHeader2
     |_item1
     |_item2
```

The problem is if i click an item it becomes selected, and stays selected if I click on a header or subheader. If a header is clicked I would like to set the `SelectedItem` to null. I am using a command to remove the `SelectedItem` from the UI, but i don't want the command to execute if a header or subheader is being clicked only when a item is being clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GroupStyle`s are not selectable, so of course your view model won't see a selection change happen.

To work around this, you can use some code behind.  What you'll notice is if you click on the items in the `ListBox`, then `ListBoxItem` will set the MouseUp event's `Handled` property to true.  If you click anywhere else on the `ListBox`, nothing handles the event.  With that being said, you can set your selected item based on the state of `Handled`.

**XAML:**

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myCVS}}"
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myItemsTemplate}"
         ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource myItemsStyle}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedListItem}"
         MouseLeftButtonUp="ListBox_MouseLeftButtonUp">
```

**Code-behind:**

```
private void ListBox_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if(!e.Handled)
    {
        var lb = sender as ListBox;
        lb.SelectedItem = null;
    }
}
```

**Addendum:**

Clicking on an already selected item will set the SelectedItem to null.  To prevent that, do this: instead of using `MouseLeftButtonUp` use `MouseDown:`

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myCVS}}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedListItem}"
         MouseDown="ListBox_MouseLeftButtonUp">
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/637e8c0001ee673cc6a6) is the state of my current application (`GroupStyle`'s) don't get drawn properly, but the implementation is what's important here.  If this doesn't do it for you, I would implement a pure MVVM approach.

Comment: Thanks, this works, i just have to tweak it a bit. It does exactly what i want, thanks!

Comment: @user1336827 good. don't forget to award bounty if it qualifies ;)

Comment: Perhaps you could help with one other bit. The item is becoming selected on the mouse down ( highlighted in the list ) on mouse up the highlight (on the selected item) is going away.  I can get around this by setting both the selected item background color and selectedItemInactive background color to transparent. And all my other code still works (commands) but i would like to visually keep the selected item highlighted. and only set it to null when a groupstle is clicked. any thoughts?

Comment: It appears that the mouse up event on the item is also being handled by this event handler in the code behind, so e.handled is false no matter what you click on. Item or group style.

Comment: I think i need to maybe detect in the event if it is a group style or not.

Comment: Actually I jumped the gun, the Mouse_Down event was not hitting my code, which indicates to me something else was handling it as i believe it is a routed event. However changing it to PreviewMouseDown created the correct effect, Selected item stays selected until a groupstyle is clicked. Which works well in the UI and also prevents the "remove" command from firing. Thanks.